# How to convert a sum of minutes to hours and minutes format

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, time

I have a column with minutes that are the result of a calculation (speed and distance).

```
=(E7/$A$2)*60
=(E8/$A$2)*60
=(E9/$A$2)*60
```

[image]

These are displayed with a quote, using a Cell Format
`#0"''"`.

Then I have a cell where I sum those minutes
`=SUM(F5:F32)`

[image]

How can I convert that sum to a number of hours and minutes, so instead of “101” it shows “1:41”.

I have tried the following formats:

- `[h]:mm` shows **2419:12**
- `[h]:mm` with the formula `=(SUM(F5:F32))/60` shows **40:19** (the same for `=(SUM(F5:F32)/60)`
- Just the `=(SUM(F5:F32)/60)` formula shows “**2**”
- Combination of `[h]:mm` and `=(SUM(F5:F32)/1140)` shows **2:07**

Not sure, if I can add links here, but here is the spreadsheet:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnVs0M9nMI3Nl4UJlx8NS4l9Q8Fpmg?e=HyoFVP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel - converting minutes to hours and minutes in hh:mm format](https://superuser.com/questions/1143399/excel-converting-minutes-to-hours-and-minutes-in-hhmm-format)

Comment: Thank you. I saw that topic earlier. It probably should help me but unfortunately it did not. I still miss something. I have shared the spreadsheet, this is the C3 cell.

Comment: "Combination of [h]:mm and =(SUM(F5:F32)/1140) shows 2:07" you need to use `1440` and not `1140` (there are 1440 minutes in a day)

Comment: I retracted my close vote - this post is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula to use is :

```
=SUM(NUMBERVALUE(F5:F32)/1440)
```

The problem is that the added `''` have confused Excel, confusion that
was resolved by using the
[NUMBERVALUE function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/numbervalue-function-1b05c8cf-2bfa-4437-af70-596c7ea7d879).

[image]

Comment: 1440 <=> 24 hours with 60 minutes each, Excel date values "uses" 1.0 as value for 24 hours

Comment: Wow! Thank you very very very much!

Answer (score 0):

More robust is to work with the Excel concept that times are stored as fractions of a day:
So your formula should divide distance by (speed per day.)
i.e. `=E7/($A$2*24)`
Then just use format hh:mm.
And with this approach you can easily carry on to E.g. multiply/add the values.
This is similar to percentages - if wanting `=33/40` as a percentage, have the formula result in a number 0.825, and use the Excel format `0.0%` to show as 82.5%, rather than multiply by 100 and add a % sign as text.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, I guess I need to understand better how Excel is handling time not to ask such questions :)

Comment: I try to "teach to fish" rather than "give a fish" :-) If it hasn't become clear yet, try entering say `=2/24+17/60/24` into a new cell, and using Format Cell | Custom to format it as `hh:mm`, which will show 02:17.

Comment: I appreciate it thank you. Otherwise, I would keep having the same questions again and again.